# WPF window in front of another WPF window

Tags: wpf, window, z-order

I have a WPF-window, in this you can click a button to see a new window. Now I want to disable, that you can click the main-window. It should be like a MessageBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `dialog.ShowDialog()`.

Modeless dialogs (via `dialog.Show`) are ones that you can interact with the background window.  Modal dialogs (via `dialog.ShowDialog()` are ones that don't allow you to interact with the parent window.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for **[Window.ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 dialogYouNeedToShow.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;
 dialogYouNeedToShow.ShowDialog();
```

*ShowDialog* will always show your dialog as a modal one, so you won't have access to background form.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
MessageBox.Show()
```

or

```
myWindowName.ShowDialog()
```

?